# Set environmental variable to the right texlive version

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) instructions to install a vanilla version of texlive. Everything worked out fine except the part where I have finalize the installation. I used `grep -n texbin /etc/environment || sudo sed -i.bak -e /PATH/s/\\\"$/:\\\/opt\\\/texbin\"/ /etc/environment` to add the path to `PATH`. After logging out and signing in `which tex` still shows `/usr/bin/tex` which is my old installation of texlive, installed using `apt-get`, instead of `opt/texbin` as it should be.

When compiling a .tex file using `xelatex` I get erorrs and the header shows that it is the 2013 version instead of the 2015 I just installed. If I use `/opt/texbin/xelatex` everything works fine.

I figured out that I should add `/opt/texbin/` at first in the `/etc/environment`. I did this, but even after rebooting `echo $PATH` doesn't show `/opt/texbin` at all and `which tex` still shows `/usr/bin/tex`.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and running in zsh.

How can I modify the file to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should put `/opt/texbin` in front of the current value of `PATH`, not at the end. What's the output of `echo $PATH` after rebooting?

Comment: `echo $PATH` outputs `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` and `/etc/environment` contains `PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: Well, it seems that the change has not been seen. I usually go for the `/etc/profile.d` route, by adding a `texlive.sh` file in that directory, containing `export PATH=/opt/texbin:${PATH}`, rather than modifying `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Ok, so I wrote the short script in that directory, but still, after rebooting `echo $PATH` doesn't contain `/opt/texbin`

Am I right that I don't have a folder `texbin` in `/opt` but rather a symlink named `texbin`?

Comment: `/opt/texbin` should be a symbolic link to `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux` . You may have some setting of the path in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, please check.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had the export settings set in `.zshrc` Added `/opt/texbin` in front and now `which tex` solves for `/opt/texbin/tex`.

Comment: I'll vote to close as off-topic, because the question is unlikely to be helpful to others, as the issue depended on your particular configuration. Which doesn't mean it was a bad question at all. Happy to have been helpful and again welcome!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to settings in `.zshrc`